# Show a homomorphism between groups induces a homomorphish between their respective quotient groups

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism, quotient-group

> Given groups $ G_1 , G_2 $ and $H_1 \unlhd G_1 , H_2 \unlhd G_2$, show that $\varphi: G_1 \to G_2$ induces $\phi: \frac{G_1}{H_1} \to \frac{G_2}{H_2}$ if $\varphi (H_1) \subset H_2$.

So taking $\varphi: G_1 \to G_2 $ and $\pi : G_2 \to \frac{G_2}{H_2} $,
we have $\overline{\varphi} : G_1 \to \frac{G_2}{H_2} $ and $\overline{\varphi} = \pi \circ \varphi  $.

Take $\psi : G_1 \to \frac{G_1}{H_1} $ by the factorization theorem $\exists \ \Phi :  \frac{G_1}{H_1} \to \frac{G_2}{H_2} $.

I don't understand why this is not the end and I must consider $\varphi (H_1) \subset H_2$

Comment: To add an example to @TsemoAristide's comment: can you make a non-zero homomorphism $\mathbb Z/5 \to \mathbb Z/ 0 = \mathbb Z$? (The point, of course, is that   $(5)$ is not a subgroup of $(0)$).

Comment: I only see your comment. Not @tsemoAristide 's

Comment: Yes - it was deleted.... But it was pretty much that, but in the abstract...  In the quotient groups, $H_i$ play the role of the unit element(s), correct? Necessarily, in  a group homomorphism, the unit element in the domain goes to the unit in the image. Therefore, in the original group, $H_1$ had better map to $H_2$ - if the map descends to the quotient groups....

Comment: oh yes, i see. I skipped a requirement of the factorization theorem. thanks @peterag